# Basic Express Routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I get the following routes to work in Express:

```
/ (get and post)
/users (get and post)
```

Right now, when I visit /users, the page renders correctly, but on submission, it runs the code in /index (post route) instead of the code in /users (post route).
My files look like this: **users.js**:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
var title = 'users';
res.render('users');
});

router.post('/',function(req,res){ ....});
```

**index.js**:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    var title = 'index';
    res.render('index');
});

router.post('/post',function(req,res){
```

app.js:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var show = require('./routes/show');
```

and in the app.use section:

```
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/show', show);
app.use('/', routes);
```

**EDIT**:
**Form** action is:

```
form(method="POST", action="/post")
```

Comment: It might help to show how you're performing the post requests (ie: through form attribute, AJAX, etc.)

Comment: Through a form submission.

Comment: @victorkohl I'm pretty sure your are right. I've added the form to the question. What should it be?

Comment: Shouldn't your form action be `/users` and not `/post`?

Comment: That's what I thought, but that does not work. Is there a mistake elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, your route is also to '/post' in index.js

Comment: Yes - What do I do to fix that? changing it to /users does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Nicholas has said in the comments, you should update your form to as follows:

#### Form

```
form(method="POST", action="/users")
```

This will hit your POST route in your users controller.

If you also desire a POST to `/` as well, you should update your `index.js` to:

#### Index.js

```
// it should be / not /post
router.post('/',function(req,res){ ... }
```

Also, be aware you'll probably need to use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to parse out the Form data.

Hope this helps!